# Making edge on Ice Sliding puzzle path finding

Tags: c, path-finding

[My apology for the title, I just specified the problem I encountered on this puzzle.

I'm making a path finding method with the least distance travelled, depending on the number of asterisks encountered.

The rules of the game is simple, traversing from A to B, but I can only move in a straight line and cannot stop moving in that direction until you hit an asterisk (or the B), as if they were sliding across every zero.

Example, the photo shows the shortest path from A to B with 23 as the total distance travelled.
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9xYE.png)

The first idea that appeared on my mind is making an adjacency matrix, initially, which I have my code here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *hehehe = fopen("input.txt","r");
    //==========================ADJACENCY MATRIX INITIALIZATION=======================================//
    int row, column, i, j;
    fscanf(hehehe,"%d",&row);
    fscanf(hehehe,"%d",&column);
    char c;
    c = fgetc(hehehe);
    int matrix[row][column];
    c = fgetc(hehehe);
    for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < column; j++)
        {
            if (c == '*'){
                matrix[i][j] = 1;
                c = fgetc(hehehe);
            }
            else if (c == 'A')
            {
                matrix[i][j] = 2;
                c = fgetc(hehehe);
            }
            else if (c == 'B')
            {
                matrix[i][j] = 3;
                c = fgetc(hehehe);
            }
            else{
                matrix[i][j] = 0;
                c = fgetc(hehehe);
            }
            if (c == '\n'){c = fgetc(hehehe);}
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < column; j++)
        {
            //if (matrix[i][j] == 1)  printf("*");
            //else    printf(" ");
            printf("%d ",matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }


    fclose(hehehe);
}
```

Any idea or suggestion for continuing for making of edge in every straight line in the photo is high appreciated. Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: Sorry, didn't get your exact question - "*for continuing for making of edge in every straight line in the photo*".

Comment: As for some algorithm, I think you are good to use BFS (since the edges have no weights, it will return the shortest path).

Comment: If you reach B, but there's no asterisk behind it to stop you, will you keep sliding past B, or will you stick to B and win?

Comment: It will stick to B :)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I think a matrix is overdoing it. Because you cannot make a move while sliding, you only need a directed graph.

There are a few things to keep in mind while making your algorithm:

- Stopping points are the goal, or any space adjacent to a wall/asterisk.
- A vertex should store two values; direction, and location.
- For each asterisk or obstacle, add adjacent spaces to the list of vertices (if they don't exist in your graph yet). They only require one direction.
- For each B, add a vertex with all possible directions. (Or one vertex for each direction, depending on whether that makes it easier).
- For each vertex, find the closest vertex in the direction stored. Draw an edge between both vertices (if it does not already exist).
- Run an appropriate search algorithm. If distance matters, use Dijkstra's. If it doesn't, use Breadth-first. If there are special scoring rules, consider A*.

Because your search space doesn't seem so large, I haven't fully optimized the algorithm. This is why I mention checking that vertices and edges aren't already added. Optimizing these is possible, and I can help with that if you need, but if-statements aren't costly enough to warrant premature optimization. Because your search space is easy to simplify, Breadth-first and Dijkstra's algorithm are absolutely perfect; they find the shortest path and their performance cost is nowhere near as high as putting them on a 2D grid.

If you're not sure of how to make your data structures, here's the way I'd approach it.

1.
    **Graph Structures**

```
Direction // x and y tuple/variable, integer, or string

Point // x and y tuple/variable. Note that you can use this as direction too 

Vertex
- Point
- Map < Direction, Edge > // each direction is linked to another vertex
                          // maps in C can be made with two arrays
                          // a vertex for each direction may be easier

Edge
- Vertex // you can store both vertices, but you only need to store the one being moved to. 
         // without OOP, reuse a simple struct before making it complex

Graph
- Vertices // array of vertex
           // each vertex stores its edges; the graph doesn't need to
```

2.
    **Pathfinder Structures**

```
Node
- Parent // a link to the previous node
         // trace the links back to construct a path
- Depth // last node's depth + 1
- Vertex // the vertex hit by the pathfinder

Path
- Nodes // while parent is not null
        // add a node to this list
        // then read it backward
```